# How did they make this glitchable_container?

Tags: html

https://versionindustries.com/

Hover over the images they use for their portfolio. That glitch is really cool to me, and I can see tons of applications for it. Does anybody know how I can replicate that? I'm not great at coding, but I'd probably understand the lingo you throw at me.

Anybody?

Comment: Please stop downvoting without giving reason. The question is a valid inquiry into the technology used, albeit very freeform and generic.

Comment: how about http://snorpey.github.io/jpg-glitch/

Answer (score 2):

Why not just inspect the code they're using and try to reverse-engineer?

```
(function($) {
    window.GlitchableImages = function(selector) {
        var base64Chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/",
            base64Map = base64Chars.split(""),
            reverseBase64Map = false,
            hover_img = false,
            elSelector = selector;

        function setupReverseBase64Map() {
            reverseBase64Map = {};
            base64Map.forEach(function(val, key) {
                reverseBase64Map[val] = key
            })
        }
        function detectJpegHeaderSize(data) {
            var jpgHeaderLength = 417;
            for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
                if (data[i] == 255 && data[i + 1] == 218) {
                    jpgHeaderLength = i + 2;
                    return jpgHeaderLength
                }
            }
            return jpgHeaderLength
        }
        function base64ToByteArray(str) {
            var result = [],
                digitNum, cur, prev;
            for (var i = 23, l = str.length; i < l; i++) {
                cur = reverseBase64Map[str.charAt(i)];
                digitNum = (i - 23) % 4;
                switch (digitNum) {
                    case 1:
                        result.push(prev << 2 | cur >> 4);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        result.push((prev & 15) << 4 | cur >> 2);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        result.push((prev & 3) << 6 | cur);
                        break
                }
                prev = cur
            }
            return result
        }
        function byteArrayToBase64(arr) {
            var result = ["data:image/jpeg;base64,"],
                byteNum, cur, prev;
            for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
                cur = arr[i];
                byteNum = i % 3;
                switch (byteNum) {
                    case 0:
                        result.push(base64Map[cur >> 2]);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        result.push(base64Map[(prev & 3) << 4 | cur >> 4]);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        result.push(base64Map[(prev & 15) << 2 | cur >> 6]);
                        result.push(base64Map[cur & 63]);
                        break
                }
                prev = cur
            }
            if (byteNum === 0) {
                result.push(base64Map[(prev & 3) << 4]);
                result.push("==")
            } else if (byteNum == 1) {
                result.push(base64Map[(prev & 15) << 2]);
                result.push("=")
            }
            return result.join("")
        }
        function glitchJpegBytes(strArr, jpgHeaderLength) {
            var rnd = Math.floor(jpgHeaderLength + Math.random() * (strArr.length - jpgHeaderLength - 4));
            strArr[rnd] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)
        }
        function glitchJpeg() {
            try {
                var glitchCopy = hover_img.dataArr.slice();
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    glitchJpegBytes(glitchCopy, hover_img.headerLength)
                }
                var new_img = new Image;
                new_img.onload = function() {
                    if (typeof hover_img.ctx === "undefined") return;
                    hover_img.ctx.drawImage(new_img, 0, 0, hover_img.width, hover_img.height)
                };
                new_img.src = byteArrayToBase64(glitchCopy)
            } catch (e) {}
        }
        function unglitch(this_img) {
            try {
                var new_img = new Image;
                new_img.onload = function() {
                    this_img.ctx.drawImage(new_img, 0, 0, this_img.width, this_img.height)
                };
                new_img.src = byteArrayToBase64(this_img.dataArr)
            } catch (e) {}
        }
        function setupGlitchableImage(event) {
            var img = this.page_img;
            var $img = $(img);
            var $canvas = $('<canvas width="' + $img.width() + '" height="' + $img.height() + '">');
            $img.wrap('<span class="glitchable_container"></span>');
            $img.after($canvas);
            try {
                img.ctx = $canvas[0].getContext("2d");
                img.ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, $img.width(), $img.height());
                img.jpgImgData = $canvas[0].toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                img.dataArr = base64ToByteArray(img.jpgImgData);
                img.headerLength = detectJpegHeaderSize(img.dataArr)
            } catch (e) {}
        }
        function onImageMouseOver(event) {
            hover_img = $(event.target).prev("img")[0]
        }
        function onImageMouseMove(event) {
            requestAnimationFrame(glitchJpeg)
        }
        function onImageMouseOut(event) {
            unglitch(hover_img);
            hover_img = false
        }
        function resize() {
            $(".glitchable_container canvas").each(function() {
                var $img = $(this).siblings("img");
                $(this).attr("width", $img.width()).attr("height", $img.height())
            })
        }
        function init() {
            if (!reverseBase64Map) {
                setupReverseBase64Map()
            }
            $(elSelector).each(function() {
                if (this.ctx) {
                    return
                }
                this.load_img = new Image;
                this.load_img.page_img = this;
                $(this.load_img).load(setupGlitchableImage);
                this.load_img.src = this.getAttribute("src")
            });
            $("body").on("mouseover", ".glitchable_container", onImageMouseOver).on("mousemove", ".glitchable_container", onImageMouseMove).on("mouseout", ".glitchable_container", onImageMouseOut)
        }
        return {
            onResize: resize,
            init: init
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: So, I'm completely new at JQuery. How would I implement a code like this, or otherwise use it? Hope I'm not too newbish for the site. Just really want to learn how this all works!

Comment: It might be a bit advanced for someone just delving into jQuery to take on, but basically you would add the function above to a javascript file and include that file in your HTML. You would also need to change the DIV IDs/Classes in the javascript function to match your own DIVs(or just create your DIVs using the same IDs/Classes that they are using).